# Proof of a Proposition regarding the Integral $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial B} \frac{1}{\zeta-z} d\zeta$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

First some context:

I am reading about the Integration of

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial B} \frac{1}{\zeta-z} d\zeta$

It seems that if, $z \neq  c$ the "plain" integration does not work.

So in the book I am reading there is a Proposition to solve this problem (using geometric series).

Proposition:
The following equations

(1) $\frac{1}{\zeta -z}=\frac{1}{\zeta-c}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z-c}{\zeta-c})^n$ holds for all $|z-c|< |\zeta-c|$
(2) $\frac{1}{\zeta -z}=\frac{-1}{z-c}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{\zeta-c}{z-c})^n$ holds for all $|z-c|> |\zeta-c|$
Thhe series (1) respectivly (2) converge as a series in $\zeta$ on a given disc $B=B_r(c)$ on $\partial B $ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ \ $\partial B$

My problem regards the proof of this Proposition:
Proof:

(*) $\frac{1}{\zeta-z}=\frac{1}{\zeta-c} \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-c}{\zeta-c}}=\frac{1}{\zeta-c}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z-c}{\zeta-c})^n$
for $|z-c|<|\zeta-c|:=r$, i.e. $z \in B_r(c)$
and

(* *) $\frac{1}{\zeta-z}=\frac{1}{z-c}\frac{-1}{1-\frac{\zeta-c}{z-c}}=\frac{1}{z-c}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{\zeta-c}{z-c})^n$ for r<|z-c|, i.e. $z \notin \overline{B_r(c)}$

Now define $q:=|z-c|r^{-1}$,thus $0 \leq q<1$ for fixed $z \in B$ and $max_{\zeta \in \partial B}|(\frac{z-c}{\zeta-c})^n|=q^n$. Hence the series (1) in $\zeta$ is convergent on $\partial B$. The convergence of (2) can be proven in a similar way.

My thoughts and question:

So in (*) one just rewrites $\frac{1}{\zeta-z}$ such that one can use the formular for the geometric series i.e. $\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-c}{\zeta-c}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z-c}{\zeta-c})^n$. In this case the series converges because $|z-c|< |\zeta-c|$.

In ( * * ) the same happens but I don't see what happens with the minus in $\frac{-1}{1-\frac{\zeta-c}{z-c}}$.
Shouldn't (* *) look like this:
$\frac{1}{\zeta-z}=\frac{1}{z-c}\frac{-1}{1-\frac{\zeta-c}{z-c}}=-\frac{1}{z-c}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{\zeta-c}{z-c})^n$

Comment: Looks like it's just a printing error. (2) and (**) you typed are different.

Comment: $\delta B$ is supposed to be $\partial B$. And what do you mean by $z\ne c$. What is $c$?

Comment: @user1046533 $c$ is the center of the disc $B_r(c)$ with radius $r$ , $z$ is some fixed complex number.

Comment: I see. $B$ is only defined later. Then you probably want to replace $B$ with what it is in the post. Instead of $\delta B$, it is $\partial B_r(c)$ (`$\partial B_r(c)$`).